# Awesome wm - Big font and panel size problem

Tags: kde-plasma, awesome-wm, kdenlive

I hope I ask the right question, Thanks in advance for helping.

I had a bad kdenlive theme running on Archlinux with awesome wm, so I installed a recommended plugins to fix it

```
sudo pacman -S breeze frei0r-plugins dfgrab dvgrab recordmydesktop dvdauthor
yay -S kdebase-runtime
```

It fixed the theme and buttons went visible. However, after rebooting I had my panel and icons of my Awesome wm totally maximized as in the following picture. [desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWxBl.png)

I ran the xrandr as a first guess but the resolution was normal as always

```
xrandr | head
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
2 LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 309mm x 174mm
3    1366x768      59.99*+  40.00
```

I then opened the awesome configuration file rc.lua, and the top and side panel sizes are also the same.

```
local SidePanel = function(s)
local panel = wibox({
  ontop = true,
  screen = s,
  height = s.geometry.height,
  width = dpi(35)})

local TopPanel = function(s)
local panel =
wibox({
  ontop = true,
  screen = s,
  height = dpi(26),
  width = s.geometry.width-45})
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the installed apps and plugins. and I hate to remove them without fixing it and keep my kdenlive theme without visible button colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested by this thread : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271094

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the proper fix for the scaling issue.
I had to timeshift to earlier proper image.

But,

I got to fixed the theme of kdenlive later without any scale changing by installing the complete "plasma-workspace" with all dependencies including breeze theme.

- as I said, it added the needed styles to kdenlive,
- It didn't change my awesome wm scaling and,
- I now have another desktop environment just in case.